# ms excel - data validation for 2 drop down list

Tags: excel

I'm looking for the solution in excel data validation for 2 drop down list.
When I choose 1st drop down list 2nd drop down list will auto populate the correct value from table. If user choose 2nd drop down list 1st drop down list will auto populate the value also.
Can someone help me on this issue ?

I attach the sample file for my problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Npw.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1AU9.jpg)

thanks!

[Sample File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx50wsi38qpo3hx/excel-data-validation.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Did you look on Google? Plenty of examples of cascading data validation there...

Comment: I agree with @jeffreyweir. Please do some research, then take the [tour] and learn [ask] a question here.

Comment: yes. I had search from google, but those example only work for 1 way... change 1st drop down list populate value to 2nd drop down list. But what i need 2 way. change 2nd drop down list will populate value to 1st drop down list. maybe my knowledge was limited so need someone help to figure out how to do it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do a two way I don't think is going to work in the way you are trying so I am not surprised the examples you found were for one-way. I am open to being corrected.

You could hack around it for example using two form control listboxes linked to the same cell so a selection in one updates the other.

Then because an item might be out of view listbox underneath have two cells which use the linked cell to index back into the source lists.

[image: Example]

In the example above, there are two list boxes from form controls in developer tab (customize ribbon > add developer tab.

Developer tab form control - 2nd from the right

[image: Developer tab]

You add two of these in to the sheet.

Right click format control on each one

[image: Format control]

Set the input range to the range containing your list of values for that listbox and set the linked cell e.g. G1

[image: Setting form control linked cell and input range]

Ensure that whilst you select different input ranges for each list box, they should have the same linked cell e.g. G1.

Underneath the listboxes put a formula which uses the linked cell G1 to index back into the source lists for each listbox so you can retrieve the selected value and have it visible, in case not visible within listbox.

[image: Example index]

Example testing:

[image: test run]

Comment: thanks you so much for your solution. 
if my input file got 1 line will be best using listbox. 
But my input line could be more than 20 or 30 line per sheet.

Comment: my problem here is not only 1 input line. My actual input file will have 12 worksheet & each worksheet will have 20 ~ 30 line for user to input. That mean I need to create 12*(30)*(2) = 720 listbox inside my working file. Isn't good solution ? Kindly advice.

Comment: How else where you planning on doing this though? It is a dependant validation you are asking for I believe. You may be able to get away with copying some. I am unclear what you mean by the 20-30 line for user to input? The lists should be set up already and the user is simply having their input validated against those lists.

Comment: item code & description will be in drop down list ... all this can be same come from diffrent document no. user will choose item code or desc refer to hard copy of document.